# Limit One category to One Product in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to limit one product in one category but if the person changes their mind, it will replace their previous item added to cart from that category instead of giving an error  (If that makes any sense).

Here's the code I'm working with...

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'bbloomer_only_one_in_cart', 99, 2 );

function bbloomer_only_one_in_cart( $passed, $added_product_id ) {
   wc_empty_cart();
   return $passed;
}
```

This is almost perfect but it does it to all categories and I want it to do it for just one category.  Please can you let me know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks for your help in advance

Stef

Comment: Have you tried by using [is_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/)?

Comment: Hi I've tried...  add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'bbloomer_only_one_in_cart', 99, 2 );
   if ( is_category( 'spot-the-difference' ) ) {
function bbloomer_only_one_in_cart( $passed, $added_product_id ) {
   wc_empty_cart();
   return $passed;
}
}

Comment: Could you please add further explanation about your problem?

Comment: Sure, So I want the customer to buy as many tickets as they want but can only choose 1 difference (here's the link... https://www.leanworks.co.uk/watches/product/power-player/ )